# Can't get property from service Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I've been learning Angular during a week by doing a simple web store. I'm still on the basis and I'm trying to load a menu with data from a REST service. For that I'm using the following configuration:

**categories.services.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http }  from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()
export class CategoriesService {

    private categories = [];

    constructor(private http: Http){
        this.setCategories();
    };

    setCategories(){
        if (this.categories != []){
            this.http.get('http://someurl:1234/someapi/somevalue')
            .toPromise()
            .then((data) => {
                console.log('inside');
                console.log(data.json().response);
                this.categories = data.json().response;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
    }

    function getCategories(){
        return this.categories; 
    }

}
```

**main.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoriesService } from '../categories/categories.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-main',
    templateUrl: './main.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})

export class MainComponent{

    categories = [];

    constructor(private cat:CategoriesService){
        this.categories = cat.getCategories;
        console.log(this.categories);
    }

    notify(private new_categories){
        this.categories = new_categories;
    }

}
```

The problem here is that **in the web console I can see the response of the REST service as expected, but the log inside the component prints an empty array**. Thank you and sorry my English

Comment: call the function for one. `this.categories = cat.getCategories();`

Comment: Have you reqistered the categoryService in app.module.ts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is asynchronous, so what is most likely going on, is that when you call `getCategories`, the variable `categories` is yet to have a value. What we usually do, is subscribe directly to the request in the component, so modify your code to such:

Service:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class CategoriesService {

  constructor(private http: Http){ }

  getCategories(){
    return this.http.get('http://someurl:1234/someapi/somevalue')
      .map(res => res.json().response)
  }

}
```

Component:

```ts
categories = [];

constructor(private cat:CategoriesService){ }

ngOnInit() { 
  this.cat.getCategories()
    .subscribe(data => {
       this.categories = data;
       console.log(this.categories)
    })
}
```

If you are looking for not making the request if "it has been done before", use a variable in the service, check if it has values before making the http-request, else return it as an Observable. The component stays the same, it just subscribes to the Observable coming from the service, not aware of it being the result of a http-request or not.

Something in the line of:

```ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

@Injectable()
export class CategoriesService {

  private categories = [];

  constructor(private http: Http){ }

  getCategories(){
    if(this.categories.length) {
      return Observable.of(this.categories)
    } else { 
      return this.http.get('http://someurl:1234/someapi/somevalue')
        .do(res => this.categories = res.json().response)
        .map(res => res.json().response)
    }
  }
}
```

Also consider using the `HttpClient` instead of `Http`, as `Http` is deprecated.

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply this soon, but this is exactly what I needed, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the paranthesis while calling a function, it should be as follows,

```
constructor(private cat:CategoriesService){
        this.categories = cat.getCategories(); //check this line
        console.log(this.categories);
}
```